# MySQL - table text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm trying to insert into MySQL message table an text, but it seems it can't work. I tried hundreds of possibilities how to make it work but i fail

when you read this sentence

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rapoarte (emitator,rec....
```

down I'm trying to integrate an table but I don't know why it doesn't work at this part

```
<td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."'>Accepta invitatia</a></td>
```

or this neither

```
<td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."'>Refuza invitatia</a></td>
```

The MySQL table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `rapoarte`;
CREATE TABLE `rapoarte` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `emitator` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receptor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titlu` text NOT NULL,
  `descriere` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Code**

```
$selectare = mysql_query("select * from membri where id !=".$citeste['id']);
 $g = mysql_fetch_array($selectare);

 $clan_nume = $klan_info['clan_nume'];
 $clan_id_test = $klan_info['clan_uid'];

if ($_GET['in']>0)
{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO rapoarte (emitator,receptor,titlu,descriere)
            VALUES(".$citeste['id'].",'".$g['id']."','Invitatie','
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Aceasta este o invitatie a clanului $clan_nume</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."'>Accepta invitatia</a></td>
            <td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."'>Refuza invitatia</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>')");

}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - i readed the article you gave me, but i can't use  MySQLi , i dont understand it... My entire site is build on mysql_connect functions

Comment: Glad that you took the time to read it. It's just a matter of getting into the habit of using `mysqli_` functions. Start by [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and testing the differences. Then implement.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO when i will finish the site with all his functions i will take my time to translate ( or "evolve") into mysqli

Comment: That's great to hear. That's a good sign of a great developer.

Comment: have a nice day, and thanks for helping me so quick @FreshPrinceOfSO

Till next time, AlexGoaga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at what you're trying to `INSERT` you would see that you're passing unescaped single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO rapoarte (emitator,receptor,titlu,descriere)
        VALUES(,'','Invitatie','
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Aceasta este o invitatie a clanului </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre='>Accepta invitatia</a></td>
        <td><a href='alianta_principal.php?catre='>Refuza invitatia</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>')
```

You need to escape them or optimally, used binded parameters with prepared statements.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rapoarte (emitator,receptor,titlu,descriere)
        VALUES(".$citeste['id'].",'".$g['id']."','Invitatie','
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Aceasta este o invitatie a clanului $clan_nume</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href=\'alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."\'>Accepta invitatia</a></td>
        <td><a href=\'alianta_principal.php?catre=".$g['id']."\'>Refuza invitatia</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>')");
```

Comment: The double quotes can contain single quotes and there is no need to escape them as you said.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan Care to test your theory?

Comment: Yes, i know that , but you must wait "You can accept an answer in 4 minutes"

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Just run the following code: `echo "It's worked"`

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan We're talking about SQL queries; not strings.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Sorry, I didn't paid attention to it.